# COOKIE_DOMAIN setting confusion

Tags: multisite, wp-config, cookies, cdn

I'm upgrading my website and it's using WordPress. I'm using sub-domain `cdn` for CDN and it needs to be cookieless.

Currently my website is a multi-network of multisites (both are subdirectory installs), with the subdomain `www` hosting my main music project, and subdomain `photo` hosting my photography project.

The plugin I'm using for that kind of multi-network is: https://github.com/stuttter/wp-multi-network

I need to use Single Sign-on. And this leads me to a confusion while setting `COOKIE_DOMAIN` in `wp-config.php`. I can set like the plugin's documentation said:

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN',     'mydomain.com'        );
```

but I know this would make cookies served from `cdn.mydomain.com`.

How can I set `COOKIE_DOMAIN` in order to serve cookies from only two subdomains `www` and `photo`?

Or do I have to use another domain name just for CDN?

Comment: Is `cdn.mydomain.com` on of the sites in your WordPress Network?

Comment: No. `cdn.mydomain.com` is hosted on another server (Google App Engine).

Comment: So then this sentence is confusing: »but I know this would make cookies served from `cdn.mydomain.com`«. Why should a constant in your WP config affect other hosts?

Comment: Thank you! I've just tested my site using YSlow on GTmetrix. My CDN is cookie-free with that setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `cdn.mydomain.com` is not part of your WordPress network, it wont be affected by your settings.

The `COOKIE_DOMAIN` constant should only be used if you want to serve cookies from a single domain *for all your sites in the network*. If you omit the constant or set it to an empty value, cookies will belong to the domain their requested from. Thats the configuration you want to use for multisite/network environments especially when it comes to different domains.

Answer (score 8):

I have been struggling with using the multisite domains of native 4.x wordpress.

Despite finding references, saying these lines corrected the error, neither of these setting worked:

```
//define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', false);
//define( ‘COOKIE_DOMAIN’, $_SERVER[ ‘HTTP_HOST’ ] );
```

In the end, I added the following lines of code instead, and it worked marvellously...

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Not sure if this will be good for you?

- I'm posting this mainly for future searchers who are having troubles.

Comment: This broke my site entirely

Comment: if it broke you're site then simply remove the code, and relogin setting the original values.  This simply sets the cookie values, it doesn't affect database ETC.  Note: my site runs on the root directory (domain.com/) so if you're in a sub directory (domain.com/wordpress) then you'd have to set cookiepath as /wordpress/  -

Comment: Hey Wayne, that's the first thing I did. However, neither removing those definitions nor setting them to any other value was able to get the sites to work again. I had limited luck using a sunrise.php... but was never able to log in. I am on Google Cloud VM. I ended up restoring a disk snapshot and abandoning hope that native WPMU domain mapping can work. I'm back to using plugins.